# MongoDb / Mongoose Aggregation. Querying against the foreign record

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my query structure to get joined transactions, joining on contactId to contact._id, etc.  It works fine.  Notice the **$match: query** at the top.

```
myAggregate = [
    { $sort: { date: -1 } },
    {
        $match: query
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "contacts", // collection name in db
            localField: "contactId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "contact"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$contact"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "matters", // collection name in db
            localField: "matterId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matter"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$matter"
    }
];
```

Just ahead of the aggregate, above, is the containing function with the parameters used to form the query.  Here is its declaration (note **contactId** in the parameter list):

```
// Get Billing Entries according to filter criteria.
exports.getJoinedTransactions = function(firmId, page, pageSize, billerId, contactId, matterId, words, billingStatus, dateBeginning, dateEnding, transactionType, cb) {

    let firmIdToObjId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(global.user.firmId);
    let query = { firmId: firmIdToObjId };

    if ( typeof billerId === "object" ) {
        billerId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(billerId);
        query.contactId = billerId;
    }

    if ( typeof matterId === "object" ) {
        matterId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(matterId);
        query.matterId = matterId;
    }

    <-- I need to add a query property of contactId here.
    if (type of... 

    ....
```

The primary records returned from the above join operation are transactions.  I need to query the transaction to see that the contactId of its joined matter (the foreign collection) matches the contactId sent as a parameter.

Kind of like:

```
if ( typeof query.matter.contactId === "object" ) {
        contactId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(contactId);
        query.matter.contactId = contactId;
}
```

But I just tried this, and it doesn't work.  I get:  Cannot set property 'contactId' of undefined.

Comment: You will require an another query param with an extra  match stage. Something like `query2 = {"matter.contactId": contactId}` in your if block and match stage like `{$match: query2 }`  after your last $unwind stage. Also change the if condition to typeof contactId === "object"

Comment: @Veeram to the rescue, again!  ;-)  I generally understand what you are advising, but it would be great if you could provide the syntax.  Once I see it, I will probably understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require an another query param with an extra match stage.

Something like `query2 = {"matter.contactId": contactId}` and match stage like `{$match: query2 }` after last unwind stage. Also, change the if condition to `typeof contactId === "object"`.

```
if ( typeof contactId === "object" ) {
        contactId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(contactId);
        query2 = {"matter.contactId": contactId}
}
```

and

```
myAggregate = [
    ....
    {
        $match: query
    }
    ....
    {
        $unwind: "$matter"
    },
    {
        $match: query2
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  As usual, your solution works.  Can you direct me to some reading which breaks down the stages in terms which are easy to understand?  I am not sure of what "unwinding" really does, for example.

Comment: You are very welcome. Mongodb documentation is pretty good. You can find all the pipeline stages [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)